# Change proportion of zoom in facet_zoom [ggplot2]

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, ggforce

I would like to change the proportion of the graph covered by the "zoom". If we look at the following image we are at a ratio "graph:zoom" around 1:2 I would like instead a ratio 2:1. In other words, what I want is to reduce the height of the zoom. How should I proceed?
[image: wrong proportion plot]
Here is my code

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyverse)
require(ggforce)
HY <- DebitH %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Débit_horaire)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 6/10, size = 0.3, color = "blue") +
  geom_line(alpha = 4/10, size = 0.5, color = "blue") +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Débit Horaire (m3/s)")+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "grey",
                                          size = 0.25,
                                          linetype = 2),
        legend.position = "none") +
  facet_zoom(xlim = as.POSIXct(c("2021-01-15 00:00:00","2021-02-15 00:00:00")))
```

And here you will find a sample of the data

```
DebitH <-
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1610233200, 1610236800, 1610240400, 
1610244000, 1610247600, 1610251200, 1610254800, 1610258400, 1610262000, 
1610265600, 1610269200, 1610272800, 1610276400, 1610280000, 1610283600, 
1610287200, 1610290800, 1610294400, 1610298000, 1610301600, 1610305200, 
1610308800, 1610312400, 1610316000, 1610319600, 1610323200, 1610326800, 
1610330400, 1610334000, 1610337600, 1610341200, 1610344800, 1610348400, 
1610352000, 1610355600, 1610359200, 1610362800, 1610366400, 1610370000, 
1610373600, 1610377200, 1610380800, 1610384400, 1610388000, 1610391600, 
1610395200, 1610398800, 1610402400, 1610406000, 1610409600, 1610413200, 
1610416800, 1610420400, 1610424000, 1610427600, 1610431200, 1610434800, 
1610438400, 1610442000, 1610445600, 1610449200, 1610452800, 1610456400, 
1610460000, 1610463600, 1610467200, 1610470800, 1610474400, 1610478000, 
1610481600, 1610485200, 1610488800, 1610492400, 1610496000, 1610499600, 
1610503200, 1610506800, 1610510400, 1610514000, 1610517600, 1610521200, 
1610524800, 1610528400, 1610532000, 1610535600, 1610539200, 1610542800, 
1610546400, 1610550000, 1610553600, 1610557200, 1610560800, 1610564400, 
1610568000, 1610571600, 1610575200, 1610578800, 1610582400, 1610586000, 
1610589600, 1610593200, 1610596800, 1610600400, 1610604000, 1610607600, 
1610611200, 1610614800, 1610618400, 1610622000, 1610625600, 1610629200, 
1610632800, 1610636400, 1610640000, 1610643600, 1610647200, 1610650800, 
1610654400, 1610658000, 1610661600, 1610665200, 1610668800, 1610672400, 
1610676000, 1610679600, 1610683200, 1610686800, 1610690400, 1610694000, 
1610697600, 1610701200, 1610704800, 1610708400, 1610712000, 1610715600, 
1610719200, 1610722800, 1610726400, 1610730000, 1610733600, 1610737200, 
1610740800, 1610744400, 1610748000, 1610751600, 1610755200, 1610758800, 
1610762400, 1610766000, 1610769600, 1610773200, 1610776800, 1610780400, 
1610784000, 1610787600, 1610791200, 1610794800, 1610798400, 1610802000, 
1610805600, 1610809200, 1610812800, 1610816400, 1610820000, 1610823600, 
1610827200, 1610830800, 1610834400, 1610838000, 1610841600, 1610845200, 
1610848800, 1610852400, 1610856000, 1610859600, 1610863200, 1610866800, 
1610870400, 1610874000, 1610877600, 1610881200, 1610884800, 1610888400, 
1610892000, 1610895600, 1610899200, 1610902800, 1610906400, 1610910000, 
1610913600, 1610917200, 1610920800, 1610924400, 1610928000, 1610931600, 
1610935200, 1610938800, 1610942400, 1610946000, 1610949600, 1610953200, 
1610956800, 1610960400, 1610964000, 1610967600, 1610971200, 1610974800, 
1610978400, 1610982000, 1610985600, 1610989200, 1610992800, 1610996400, 
1.611e+09, 1611003600, 1611007200, 1611010800, 1611014400, 1611018000, 
1611021600, 1611025200, 1611028800, 1611032400, 1611036000, 1611039600, 
1611043200, 1611046800, 1611050400, 1611054000, 1611057600, 1611061200, 
1611064800, 1611068400, 1611072000, 1611075600, 1611079200, 1611082800, 
1611086400, 1611090000, 1611093600, 1611097200, 1611100800, 1611104400, 
1611108000, 1611111600, 1611115200, 1611118800, 1611122400, 1611126000, 
1611129600, 1611133200, 1611136800, 1611140400, 1611144000, 1611147600, 
1611151200, 1611154800, 1611158400, 1611162000, 1611165600, 1611169200, 
1611172800, 1611176400, 1611180000, 1611183600, 1611187200, 1611190800, 
1611194400, 1611198000, 1611201600, 1611205200, 1611208800, 1611212400, 
1611216000, 1611219600, 1611223200, 1611226800, 1611230400, 1611234000, 
1611237600, 1611241200, 1611244800, 1611248400, 1611252000, 1611255600, 
1611259200, 1611262800, 1611266400, 1611270000, 1611273600, 1611277200, 
1611280800, 1611284400, 1611288000, 1611291600, 1611295200, 1611298800, 
1611302400, 1611306000, 1611309600, 1611313200, 1611316800, 1611320400, 
1611324000, 1611327600, 1611331200, 1611334800, 1611338400, 1611342000, 
1611345600, 1611349200, 1611352800, 1611356400, 1611360000, 1611363600, 
1611367200, 1611370800, 1611374400, 1611378000, 1611381600, 1611385200, 
1611388800, 1611392400, 1611396000, 1611399600, 1611403200, 1611406800, 
1611410400, 1611414000, 1611417600, 1611421200, 1611424800, 1611428400, 
1611432000, 1611435600, 1611439200, 1611442800, 1611446400, 1611450000, 
1611453600, 1611457200, 1611460800, 1611464400, 1611468000, 1611471600, 
1611475200, 1611478800, 1611482400, 1611486000, 1611489600, 1611493200, 
1611496800, 1611500400, 1611504000, 1611507600, 1611511200, 1611514800, 
1611518400, 1611522000, 1611525600, 1611529200, 1611532800, 1611536400, 
1611540000, 1611543600, 1611547200, 1611550800, 1611554400, 1611558000, 
1611561600, 1611565200, 1611568800, 1611572400, 1611576000, 1611579600, 
1611583200, 1611586800, 1611590400, 1611594000, 1611597600, 1611601200, 
1611604800, 1611608400, 1611612000, 1611615600, 1611619200, 1611622800, 
1611626400, 1611630000, 1611633600, 1611637200, 1611640800, 1611644400, 
1611648000, 1611651600, 1611655200, 1611658800, 1611662400, 1611666000, 
1611669600, 1611673200, 1611676800, 1611680400, 1611684000, 1611687600, 
1611691200, 1611694800, 1611698400, 1611702000, 1611705600, 1611709200, 
1611712800, 1611716400, 1611720000, 1611723600, 1611727200, 1611730800, 
1611734400, 1611738000, 1611741600, 1611745200, 1611748800, 1611752400, 
1611756000, 1611759600, 1611763200, 1611766800, 1611770400, 1611774000, 
1611777600, 1611781200, 1611784800, 1611788400, 1611792000, 1611795600, 
1611799200, 1611802800, 1611806400, 1611810000, 1611813600, 1611817200, 
1611820800, 1611824400, 1611828000, 1611831600, 1611835200, 1611838800, 
1611842400, 1611846000, 1611849600, 1611853200, 1611856800, 1611860400, 
1611864000, 1611867600, 1611871200, 1611874800, 1611878400, 1611882000, 
1611885600, 1611889200, 1611892800, 1611896400, 1611900000, 1611903600, 
1611907200, 1611910800, 1611914400, 1611918000, 1611921600, 1611925200, 
1611928800, 1611932400, 1611936000, 1611939600, 1611943200, 1611946800, 
1611950400, 1611954000, 1611957600, 1611961200, 1611964800, 1611968400, 
1611972000, 1611975600, 1611979200, 1611982800, 1611986400, 1611990000, 
1611993600, 1611997200, 1612000800, 1612004400, 1612008000, 1612011600, 
1612015200, 1612018800, 1612022400, 1612026000, 1612029600, 1612033200, 
1612036800, 1612040400, 1612044000, 1612047600, 1612051200, 1612054800, 
1612058400, 1612062000, 1612065600, 1612069200, 1612072800, 1612076400, 
1612080000, 1612083600, 1612087200, 1612090800, 1612094400, 1612098000, 
1612101600, 1612105200, 1612108800, 1612112400, 1612116000, 1612119600, 
1612123200, 1612126800, 1612130400, 1612134000, 1612137600, 1612141200, 
1612144800, 1612148400, 1612152000, 1612155600, 1612159200, 1612162800, 
1612166400, 1612170000, 1612173600, 1612177200, 1612180800, 1612184400, 
1612188000, 1612191600, 1612195200, 1612198800, 1612202400, 1612206000, 
1612209600, 1612213200, 1612216800, 1612220400, 1612224000, 1612227600, 
1612231200, 1612234800, 1612238400, 1612242000, 1612245600, 1612249200, 
1612252800, 1612256400, 1612260000, 1612263600, 1612267200, 1612270800, 
1612274400, 1612278000, 1612281600, 1612285200, 1612288800, 1612292400, 
1612296000, 1612299600, 1612303200, 1612306800, 1612310400, 1612314000, 
1612317600, 1612321200, 1612324800, 1612328400, 1612332000, 1612335600, 
1612339200, 1612342800, 1612346400, 1612350000, 1612353600, 1612357200, 
1612360800, 1612364400, 1612368000, 1612371600, 1612375200, 1612378800, 
1612382400, 1612386000, 1612389600, 1612393200, 1612396800, 1612400400, 
1612404000, 1612407600, 1612411200, 1612414800, 1612418400, 1612422000, 
1612425600, 1612429200, 1612432800, 1612436400, 1612440000, 1612443600, 
1612447200, 1612450800, 1612454400, 1612458000, 1612461600, 1612465200, 
1612468800, 1612472400, 1612476000, 1612479600, 1612483200, 1612486800, 
1612490400, 1612494000, 1612497600, 1612501200, 1612504800, 1612508400, 
1612512000, 1612515600, 1612519200, 1612522800, 1612526400, 1612530000, 
1612533600, 1612537200, 1612540800, 1612544400, 1612548000, 1612551600, 
1612555200, 1612558800, 1612562400, 1612566000, 1612569600, 1612573200, 
1612576800, 1612580400, 1612584000, 1612587600, 1612591200, 1612594800, 
1612598400, 1612602000, 1612605600, 1612609200, 1612612800, 1612616400, 
1612620000, 1612623600, 1612627200, 1612630800, 1612634400, 1612638000, 
1612641600, 1612645200, 1612648800, 1612652400, 1612656000, 1612659600, 
1612663200, 1612666800, 1612670400, 1612674000, 1612677600, 1612681200, 
1612684800, 1612688400, 1612692000, 1612695600, 1612699200, 1612702800, 
1612706400, 1612710000, 1612713600, 1612717200, 1612720800, 1612724400, 
1612728000, 1612731600, 1612735200, 1612738800, 1612742400, 1612746000, 
1612749600, 1612753200, 1612756800, 1612760400, 1612764000, 1612767600, 
1612771200, 1612774800, 1612778400, 1612782000, 1612785600, 1612789200, 
1612792800, 1612796400, 1612800000, 1612803600, 1612807200, 1612810800, 
1612814400, 1612818000, 1612821600, 1612825200, 1612828800, 1612832400, 
1612836000, 1612839600, 1612843200, 1612846800, 1612850400, 1612854000, 
1612857600, 1612861200, 1612864800, 1612868400, 1612872000, 1612875600, 
1612879200, 1612882800, 1612886400, 1612890000, 1612893600, 1612897200, 
1612900800, 1612904400, 1612908000, 1612911600, 1612915200, 1612918800, 
1612922400, 1612926000, 1612929600, 1612933200, 1612936800, 1612940400, 
1612944000, 1612947600, 1612951200, 1612954800, 1612958400, 1612962000, 
1612965600, 1612969200, 1612972800, 1612976400, 1612980000, 1612983600, 
1612987200, 1612990800, 1612994400, 1612998000, 1613001600, 1613005200, 
1613008800, 1613012400, 1613016000, 1613019600, 1613023200, 1613026800, 
1613030400, 1613034000, 1613037600, 1613041200, 1613044800, 1613048400, 
1613052000, 1613055600, 1613059200, 1613062800, 1613066400, 1613070000, 
1613073600, 1613077200, 1613080800, 1613084400, 1613088000, 1613091600, 
1613095200, 1613098800, 1613102400, 1613106000, 1613109600, 1613113200, 
1613116800, 1613120400, 1613124000, 1613127600, 1613131200, 1613134800, 
1613138400, 1613142000, 1613145600, 1613149200, 1613152800, 1613156400, 
1613160000, 1613163600, 1613167200, 1613170800, 1613174400, 1613178000, 
1613181600, 1613185200, 1613188800, 1613192400, 1613196000, 1613199600, 
1613203200, 1613206800, 1613210400, 1613214000, 1613217600, 1613221200, 
1613224800, 1613228400, 1613232000, 1613235600, 1613239200, 1613242800, 
1613246400, 1613250000, 1613253600, 1613257200, 1613260800, 1613264400, 
1613268000, 1613271600, 1613275200, 1613278800, 1613282400, 1613286000, 
1613289600, 1613293200, 1613296800, 1613300400, 1613304000, 1613307600, 
1613311200, 1613314800, 1613318400, 1613322000, 1613325600, 1613329200, 
1613332800, 1613336400, 1613340000, 1613343600, 1613347200, 1613350800, 
1613354400, 1613358000, 1613361600, 1613365200, 1613368800, 1613372400, 
1613376000, 1613379600, 1613383200, 1613386800, 1613390400, 1613394000, 
1613397600, 1613401200, 1613404800, 1613408400, 1613412000, 1613415600, 
1613419200, 1613422800, 1613426400, 1613430000, 1613433600, 1613437200, 
1613440800, 1613444400, 1613448000, 1613451600, 1613455200, 1613458800, 
1613462400, 1613466000, 1613469600, 1613473200, 1613476800, 1613480400, 
1613484000, 1613487600, 1613491200, 1613494800, 1613498400, 1613502000, 
1613505600, 1613509200, 1613512800, 1613516400, 1613520000, 1613523600, 
1613527200, 1613530800, 1613534400, 1613538000, 1613541600, 1613545200, 
1613548800, 1613552400, 1613556000, 1613559600, 1613563200, 1613566800, 
1613570400, 1613574000, 1613577600, 1613581200, 1613584800, 1613588400, 
1613592000, 1613595600, 1613599200, 1613602800, 1613606400, 1613610000, 
1613613600, 1613617200, 1613620800, 1613624400, 1613628000, 1613631600, 
1613635200, 1613638800, 1613642400, 1613646000, 1613649600, 1613653200, 
1613656800, 1613660400, 1613664000, 1613667600, 1613671200, 1613674800, 
1613678400, 1613682000, 1613685600, 1613689200, 1613692800, 1613696400, 
1613700000, 1613703600, 1613707200, 1613710800, 1613714400, 1613718000, 
1613721600, 1613725200, 1613728800, 1613732400, 1613736000, 1613739600, 
1613743200, 1613746800, 1613750400, 1613754000, 1613757600, 1613761200, 
1613764800, 1613768400, 1613772000, 1613775600, 1613779200, 1613782800, 
1613786400, 1613790000, 1613793600, 1613797200, 1613800800, 1613804400, 
1613808000, 1613811600, 1613815200, 1613818800, 1613822400, 1613826000, 
1613829600, 1613833200, 1613836800, 1613840400, 1613844000, 1613847600, 
1613851200, 1613854800, 1613858400, 1613862000, 1613865600, 1613869200, 
1613872800, 1613876400, 1613880000, 1613883600, 1613887200, 1613890800, 
1613894400, 1613898000, 1613901600, 1613905200, 1613908800, 1613912400, 
1613916000, 1613919600, 1613923200, 1613926800, 1613930400, 1613934000, 
1613937600, 1613941200, 1613944800, 1613948400, 1613952000, 1613955600, 
1613959200, 1613962800, 1613966400, 1613970000, 1613973600, 1613977200, 
1613980800, 1613984400, 1613988000, 1613991600, 1613995200, 1613998800, 
1614002400, 1614006000, 1614009600, 1614013200, 1614016800, 1614020400, 
1614024000, 1614027600, 1614031200, 1614034800, 1614038400, 1614042000, 
1614045600, 1614049200, 1614052800, 1614056400, 1614060000, 1614063600, 
1614067200, 1614070800, 1614074400, 1614078000, 1614081600, 1614085200, 
1614088800, 1614092400, 1614096000, 1614099600, 1614103200, 1614106800, 
1614110400, 1614114000, 1614117600, 1614121200, 1614124800, 1614128400, 
1614132000, 1614135600, 1614139200, 1614142800, 1614146400, 1614150000, 
1614153600, 1614157200, 1614160800, 1614164400, 1614168000, 1614171600, 
1614175200, 1614178800, 1614182400, 1614186000, 1614189600, 1614193200, 
1614196800, 1614200400, 1614204000, 1614207600, 1614211200, 1614214800, 
1614218400, 1614222000, 1614225600, 1614229200, 1614232800, 1614236400, 
1614240000, 1614243600, 1614247200, 1614250800, 1614254400, 1614258000, 
1614261600, 1614265200, 1614268800, 1614272400, 1614276000, 1614279600, 
1614283200, 1614286800, 1614290400, 1614294000, 1614297600, 1614301200, 
1614304800, 1614308400, 1614312000, 1614315600, 1614319200, 1614322800, 
1614326400, 1614330000, 1614333600, 1614337200, 1614340800, 1614344400, 
1614348000, 1614351600, 1614355200, 1614358800, 1614362400, 1614366000, 
1614369600, 1614373200, 1614376800, 1614380400, 1614384000, 1614387600, 
1614391200, 1614394800, 1614398400, 1614402000, 1614405600, 1614409200, 
1614412800, 1614416400, 1614420000, 1614423600, 1614427200, 1614430800, 
1614434400, 1614438000, 1614441600, 1614445200, 1614448800, 1614452400, 
1614456000, 1614459600, 1614463200, 1614466800, 1614470400, 1614474000, 
1614477600, 1614481200, 1614484800, 1614488400, 1614492000, 1614495600, 
1614499200, 1614502800, 1614506400, 1614510000, 1614513600, 1614517200, 
1614520800, 1614524400, 1614528000, 1614531600, 1614535200, 1614538800, 
1614542400, 1614546000, 1614549600, 1614553200, 1614556800, 1614560400, 
1614564000, 1614567600, 1614571200, 1614574800, 1614578400, 1614582000, 
1614585600, 1614589200, 1614592800, 1614596400, 1614600000, 1614603600, 
1614607200, 1614610800, 1614614400, 1614618000, 1614621600, 1614625200, 
1614628800, 1614632400, 1614636000, 1614639600, 1614643200, 1614646800, 
1614650400, 1614654000, 1614657600, 1614661200, 1614664800, 1614668400, 
1614672000, 1614675600, 1614679200, 1614682800, 1614686400, 1614690000, 
1614693600, 1614697200, 1614700800, 1614704400, 1614708000, 1614711600, 
1614715200, 1614718800, 1614722400, 1614726000, 1614729600, 1614733200, 
1614736800, 1614740400, 1614744000, 1614747600, 1614751200, 1614754800, 
1614758400, 1614762000, 1614765600, 1614769200, 1614772800, 1614776400, 
1614780000, 1614783600, 1614787200, 1614790800, 1614794400, 1614798000, 
1614801600, 1614805200, 1614808800, 1614812400, 1614816000, 1614819600, 
1614823200, 1614826800, 1614830400, 1614834000, 1614837600, 1614841200, 
1614844800, 1614848400, 1614852000, 1614855600, 1614859200, 1614862800, 
1614866400, 1614870000, 1614873600, 1614877200, 1614880800, 1614884400, 
1614888000, 1614891600, 1614895200, 1614898800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Débit_horaire = c(5.052, 5.036, 5.009, 4.982, 4.958, 
4.937, 4.917, 4.885, 4.858, 4.834, 4.804, 4.786, 4.769, 4.753, 
4.741, 4.722, 4.713, 4.702, 4.689, 4.68, 4.669, 4.664, 4.658, 
4.645, 4.623, 4.595, 4.567, 4.539, 4.51, 4.48, 4.443, 4.413, 
4.381, 4.352, 4.327, 4.318, 4.291, 4.27, 4.268, 4.268, 4.265, 
4.257, 4.254, 4.258, 4.27, 4.283, 4.295, 4.299, 4.303, 4.307, 
4.305, 4.308, 4.32, 4.334, 4.355, 4.396, 4.457, 4.531, 4.624, 
4.738, 4.879, 5.057, 5.28, 5.558, 5.863, 6.186, 6.562, 6.958, 
7.327, 7.555, 7.638, 7.638, 7.577, 7.452, 7.291, 7.089, 6.867, 
6.646, 6.469, 6.301, 6.161, 6.043, 5.946, 5.872, 5.807, 5.752, 
5.702, 5.67, 5.658, 5.65, 5.647, 5.656, 5.692, 5.74, 5.786, 5.839, 
5.91, 6.003, 6.124, 6.256, 6.374, 6.489, 6.596, 6.686, 6.72, 
6.725, 6.706, 6.684, 6.646, 6.61, 6.578, 6.568, 6.554, 6.54, 
6.529, 6.535, 6.538, 6.542, 6.553, 6.531, 6.547, 6.54, 6.534, 
6.51, 6.504, 6.486, 6.462, 6.444, 6.429, 6.412, 6.395, 6.373, 
6.365, 6.354, 6.344, 6.334, 6.326, 6.315, 6.303, 6.295, 6.295, 
6.298, 6.296, 6.298, 6.289, 6.273, 6.258, 6.238, 6.225, 6.219, 
6.21, 6.213, 6.216, 6.216, 6.22, 6.222, 6.229, 6.233, 6.236, 
6.239, 6.238, 6.248, 6.258, 6.271, 6.292, 6.311, 6.33, 6.342, 
6.348, 6.358, 6.36, 6.365, 6.366, 6.359, 6.353, 6.342, 6.333, 
6.327, 6.33, 6.327, 6.319, 6.326, 6.332, 6.324, 6.34, 6.356, 
6.373, 6.402, 6.443, 6.487, 6.537, 6.571, 6.582, 6.582, 6.563, 
6.54, 6.515, 6.478, 6.442, 6.41, 6.372, 6.331, 6.304, 6.277, 
6.246, 6.218, 6.205, 6.199, 6.193, 6.186, 6.187, 6.203, 6.233, 
6.274, 6.315, 6.362, 6.4, 6.432, 6.459, 6.484, 6.512, 6.539, 
6.544, 6.548, 6.543, 6.529, 6.525, 6.593, 6.638, 6.713, 6.831, 
6.968, 7.142, 7.37, 7.656, 7.924, 8.117, 8.181, 8.262, 8.273, 
8.25, 8.243, 8.183, 8.13, 8.073, 8.021, 7.953, 7.888, 7.819, 
7.765, 7.733, 7.703, 7.675, 7.663, 7.661, 7.673, 7.701, 7.739, 
7.8, 7.843, 7.902, 7.973, 8.06, 8.136, 8.216, 8.342, 8.429, 8.585, 
8.694, 8.838, 9.026, 9.38, 9.815, 10.294, 10.786, 11.347, 11.859, 
12.233, 12.637, 12.966, 13.283, 13.685, 13.908, 14.334, 14.721, 
15.149, 15.581, 16.521, 17.244, 17.842, 18.501, 19.313, 20.18, 
20.831, 21.707, 22.559, 23.352, 24.222, 25.223, 25.933, 26.78, 
27.336, 28.231, 28.845, 29.255, 29.805, 30.559, 30.458, 30.79, 
30.01, 30.098, 29.579, 29.405, 29.149, 28.992, 28.879, 28.596, 
28.513, 27.866, 27.839, 27.721, 27.259, 27.385, 26.951, 26.759, 
26.467, 26.188, 25.971, 25.564, 25.572, 25.392, 25.243, 25.029, 
24.91, 24.723, 24.44, 24.286, 24.039, 23.907, 23.594, 23.454, 
23.31, 23.152, 22.881, 22.773, 22.481, 22.202, 21.956, 21.718, 
21.385, 21.212, 20.804, 20.526, 20.251, 19.879, 19.599, 19.357, 
19.033, 18.914, 18.647, 18.546, 18.301, 18.163, 17.975, 17.763, 
17.563, 17.43, 17.19, 17.061, 16.821, 16.673, 16.518, 16.312, 
16.137, 16.007, 15.833, 15.698, 15.528, 15.349, 15.195, 15.025, 
14.867, 14.718, 14.57, 14.357, 14.224, 14.021, 13.917, 13.79, 
13.584, 13.405, 13.267, 13.115, 13, 12.925, 12.786, 12.678, 12.518, 
12.44, 12.342, 12.221, 12.138, 12.006, 11.919, 11.84, 11.776, 
11.701, 11.605, 11.54, 11.484, 11.371, 11.321, 11.252, 11.177, 
11.123, 11.066, 11.028, 10.961, 10.917, 10.842, 10.808, 10.706, 
10.66, 10.588, 10.534, 10.496, 10.439, 10.434, 10.407, 10.393, 
10.326, 10.289, 10.243, 10.188, 10.134, 10.09, 10.07, 10.039, 
10.089, 10.19, 10.407, 10.695, 11.179, 11.769, 12.402, 13.126, 
13.95, 14.598, 15.244, 15.748, 16.186, 16.655, 16.938, 17.177, 
17.321, 17.365, 17.337, 17.256, 17.256, 17.163, 17.1, 17.143, 
17.363, 17.495, 17.883, 18.542, 19.075, 19.628, 20.129, 20.61, 
20.944, 21.508, 22.023, 22.557, 23.16, 23.827, 24.4, 24.849, 
25.24, 25.387, 25.282, 25.309, 25.296, 25.562, 25.898, 26, 26.274, 
26.225, 26.295, 26.394, 26.274, 26.071, 26.072, 26.035, 26.211, 
26.383, 26.303, 26.501, 26.474, 26.513, 26.728, 26.825, 27.036, 
27.121, 27.443, 27.65, 27.775, 27.689, 27.79, 28.197, 27.82, 
28.144, 27.998, 27.789, 27.686, 26.934, 26.954, 26.612, 26.222, 
26.192, 25.722, 25.616, 25.531, 25.292, 25.189, 24.797, 24.832, 
24.664, 24.525, 24.343, 24.419, 24.284, 24.044, 24.054, 23.818, 
23.651, 23.619, 23.587, 23.589, 23.397, 23.314, 23.144, 22.834, 
22.846, 22.571, 22.437, 22.204, 22.036, 21.734, 21.588, 21.283, 
21.018, 20.798, 20.394, 20.138, 19.926, 19.679, 19.477, 19.19, 
18.914, 18.683, 18.514, 18.243, 18.11, 17.981, 17.873, 17.723, 
17.655, 17.56, 17.496, 17.444, 17.353, 17.342, 17.289, 17.221, 
17.182, 17.05, 16.966, 16.87, 16.649, 16.514, 16.457, 16.305, 
16.172, 16.121, 16.223, 16.198, 16.412, 16.695, 16.984, 17.443, 
17.808, 18.403, 19.015, 19.509, 19.919, 20.47, 20.922, 21.258, 
21.561, 21.636, 21.557, 21.321, 21.223, 20.979, 20.834, 20.559, 
20.501, 20.434, 20.312, 20.226, 20.08, 19.971, 19.846, 19.8, 
19.712, 19.652, 19.59, 19.502, 19.442, 19.378, 19.261, 19.197, 
19.193, 19.159, 19.119, 19.053, 18.966, 18.916, 18.877, 18.774, 
18.71, 18.623, 18.501, 18.422, 18.277, 18.145, 18.057, 17.947, 
17.828, 17.73, 17.56, 17.472, 17.347, 17.187, 17.019, 16.896, 
16.784, 16.676, 16.496, 16.395, 16.255, 16.154, 16.125, 16.037, 
15.981, 15.889, 15.897, 15.811, 15.786, 15.723, 15.584, 15.535, 
15.433, 15.333, 15.291, 15.213, 15.091, 15.02, 14.928, 14.845, 
14.804, 14.916, 15.406, 15.627, 16, 16.414, 16.809, 17.147, 17.457, 
17.723, 17.973, 18.175, 18.371, 18.551, 18.613, 18.581, 18.389, 
18.036, 17.58, 17.179, 16.751, 16.425, 16.129, 15.928, 15.791, 
15.61, 15.487, 15.389, 15.363, 15.355, 15.312, 15.326, 15.301, 
15.324, 15.291, 15.266, 15.184, 15.102, 15.056, 15.008, 14.947, 
14.899, 14.84, 14.82, 14.819, 14.781, 14.766, 14.768, 14.715, 
14.696, 14.631, 14.54, 14.455, 14.344, 14.209, 14.103, 14.027, 
13.931, 13.848, 13.769, 13.662, 13.611, 13.493, 13.424, 13.358, 
13.286, 13.232, 13.132, 13.034, 12.98, 12.937, 12.86, 12.76, 
12.694, 12.604, 12.561, 12.466, 12.361, 12.257, 12.138, 12.025, 
11.95, 11.863, 11.767, 11.675, 11.554, 11.473, 11.38, 11.287, 
11.198, 11.125, 11.074, 11.007, 10.96, 10.906, 10.85, 10.768, 
10.693, 10.62, 10.513, 10.435, 10.33, 10.226, 10.147, 10.045, 
9.956, 9.844, 9.758, 9.669, 9.596, 9.542, 9.488, 9.453, 9.423, 
9.359, 9.331, 9.332, 9.307, 9.279, 9.242, 9.204, 9.147, 9.079, 
8.982, 8.892, 8.814, 8.74, 8.659, 8.602, 8.531, 8.45, 8.412, 
8.35, 8.284, 8.243, 8.202, 8.168, 8.133, 8.111, 8.08, 8.062, 
8.044, 8.024, 8.007, 7.975, 7.924, 7.867, 7.782, 7.71, 7.624, 
7.544, 7.463, 7.373, 7.297, 7.233, 7.166, 7.103, 7.052, 7.024, 
6.985, 6.938, 6.917, 6.914, 6.909, 6.893, 6.9, 6.903, 6.917, 
6.891, 6.853, 6.803, 6.749, 6.694, 6.639, 6.565, 6.483, 6.42, 
6.37, 6.32, 6.282, 6.252, 6.226, 6.204, 6.214, 6.215, 6.166, 
6.155, 6.134, 6.133, 6.158, 6.175, 6.181, 6.175, 6.167, 6.148, 
6.116, 6.082, 6.046, 6.019, 5.983, 5.962, 5.933, 5.912, 5.891, 
5.864, 5.85, 5.831, 5.822, 5.806, 5.806, 5.813, 5.828, 5.856, 
5.876, 5.907, 5.931, 5.97, 6.023, 6.055, 6.072, 6.069, 6.06, 
6.052, 6.028, 6.015, 5.987, 5.965, 5.937, 5.902, 5.869, 5.836, 
5.798, 5.77, 5.756, 5.767, 5.812, 5.869, 5.935, 6.029, 6.119, 
6.188, 6.235, 6.292, 6.332, 6.383, 6.455, 6.575, 6.634, 6.617, 
6.543, 6.441, 6.336, 6.241, 6.162, 6.08, 6.011, 5.942, 5.885, 
5.83, 5.785, 5.756, 5.729, 5.691, 5.666, 5.628, 5.581, 5.531, 
5.478, 5.431, 5.383, 5.327, 5.278, 5.23, 5.193, 5.159, 5.119, 
5.086, 5.057, 5.034, 5.016, 4.995, 4.912, 4.963, 4.987, 5.019, 
5.099, 5.21, 5.313, 5.476, 5.692, 5.883, 6.152, 6.457, 6.633, 
6.623, 6.445, 6.218, 5.996, 5.813, 5.667, 5.548, 5.461, 5.379, 
5.303, 5.24, 5.168, 5.122, 5.078, 5.044, 5.004, 4.973, 4.943, 
4.911, 4.875, 4.848, 4.823, 4.794, 4.772, 4.75, 4.727, 4.711, 
4.693, 4.668, 4.652, 4.639, 4.627, 4.617, 4.608, 4.593, 4.573, 
4.56, 4.549, 4.544, 4.541, 4.532, 4.512, 4.504, 4.493, 4.474, 
4.465, 4.45, 4.438, 4.417, 4.407, 4.396, 4.387, 4.381, 4.375, 
4.361, 4.351, 4.337, 4.334, 4.33, 4.325, 4.32, 4.311, 4.312, 
4.305, 4.291, 4.274, 4.257, 4.248, 4.233, 4.23, 4.222, 4.216, 
4.215, 4.2, 4.19, 4.184, 4.177, 4.172, 4.161, 4.152, 4.145, 4.141, 
4.136, 4.133, 4.126, 4.114, 4.099, 4.087, 4.078, 4.064, 4.05, 
4.043, 4.035, 4.025, 4.013, 4.002, 3.989, 3.979, 3.97, 3.966, 
3.958, 3.943, 3.94, 3.932, 3.928, 3.918, 3.91, 3.901, 3.88, 3.874, 
3.866, 3.849, 3.831, 3.818, 3.804, 3.795, 3.787, 3.781, 3.779, 
3.773, 3.767, 3.763, 3.757, 3.754, 3.751, 3.745, 3.738, 3.729, 
3.731, 3.724, 3.723, 3.72, 3.72, 3.709, 3.707, 3.709, 3.707, 
3.685, 3.668, 3.667, 3.682, 3.671, 3.652, 3.644, 3.635, 3.632, 
3.626, 3.617, 3.614, 3.604, 3.598, 3.591, 3.586, 3.58, 3.578, 
3.57, 3.564, 3.558, 3.547, 3.534, 3.524, 3.514, 3.499, 3.481, 
3.476, 3.459, 3.449, 3.44, 3.43, 3.414, 3.41, 3.411, 3.417, 3.431, 
3.455, 3.496, 3.53, 3.568, 3.604, 3.645, 3.685, 3.717, 3.728, 
3.727, 3.69, 3.635, 3.592, 3.558, 3.52, 3.498, 3.472, 3.44, 3.413, 
3.393, 3.37, 3.353, 3.321, 3.287, 3.261, 3.24, 3.237, 3.23, 3.227, 
3.225, 3.223, 3.233, 3.242, 3.247, 3.234, 3.208, 3.181, 3.154, 
3.134, 3.123, 3.109, 3.097, 3.091, 3.091, 3.085, 3.08, 3.074, 
3.073, 3.07, 3.046, 3.052, 3.053, 3.049, 3.046, 3.029, 3.028, 
3.018, 3.003, 2.997, 2.981, 2.971, 2.957, 2.946, 2.937, 2.931, 
2.926, 2.916, 2.907, 2.904, 2.893, 2.887, 2.876, 2.866, 2.861, 
2.854, 2.851, 2.85, 2.855, 2.865, 2.86, 2.859, 2.855, 2.843, 
2.838, 2.828, 2.806, 2.793, 2.782, 2.775, 2.77, 2.759, 2.752, 
2.744, 2.737, 2.729, 2.723, 2.719, 2.711, 2.703, 2.693, 2.697, 
2.7, 2.699, 2.695, 2.693, 2.693, 2.692, 2.69, 2.681, 2.67, 2.658, 
2.642, 2.637, 2.63, 2.623, 2.614, 2.611, 2.604, 2.604, 2.598, 
2.591, 2.593, 2.594, 2.591, 2.585, 2.602, 2.601, 2.597, 2.59, 
2.583, 2.582, 2.569, 2.562, 2.551, 2.544, 2.536, 2.537, 2.523, 
2.516, 2.513, 2.515, 2.516, 2.516, 2.519, 2.518, 2.517, 2.516, 
2.52, 2.534, 2.566, 2.607, 2.625, 2.675, 2.703, 2.742, 2.782, 
2.827, 2.956)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1297L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the size of the zoom panel relative to the main plot via the argument `zoom.size` which defaults to 2, i.e. the zoom panel is twice the size of the main panel. Hence, to achieve your desired result set `zoom.size=.5`:

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyverse)
require(ggforce)
DebitH %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Débit_horaire)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 6 / 10, size = 0.3, color = "blue") +
  geom_line(alpha = 4 / 10, size = 0.5, color = "blue") +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Débit Horaire (m3/s)") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(
      color = "grey",
      size = 0.25,
      linetype = 2
    ),
    legend.position = "none"
  ) +
  facet_zoom(xlim = as.POSIXct(c("2021-01-15 00:00:00", "2021-02-15 00:00:00")), zoom.size = .5)
```

[image]