# ggforce : force facet_zoom to set on the lateral side of the graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, ggforce

Is there a way to force the zoom from the function `facet_zoom()` from the package `ggforce` on the lateral side of the graph instead of the bottom ?

I have this code

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyverse)
require(ggforce)

g + facet_zoom(xlim = c(x1,x2)))
```

How should I proceed?

**EDIT**

Through the really good answer provided by Stefan I can add a picture representing what I want (I am definitely open for other ways to reach it).

[image: Expected graph]

Comment: any representative image you want to add? to show what you want to plot

Comment: I added one from the answer given by @stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but it requires a bit of a hack. As far as I get it from the docs this could only be achieved when zooming both in the `x` and `y` direction. To this end you could set the zoom in the y direction to `y=TRUE` and afterwards set `split=FALSE` and `horizontal = TRUE`. Doing so will place the zoom panel on the left of the main plot. Additionally we have to get rid of the background fill for the zoom in the `y` direction via `theme` option `zoom.y`.

Using the example data and code from your former [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74321009/change-proportion-of-zoom-in-facet-zoom-ggplot2):

Note: One side effect of using `theme_bw` is that we get some segments at the panel borders which connect the main and the zoom panel. Personally I didn't like that so I added `color=NA` to `theme(zoom.y = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA))` to remove these lines.

```
DebitH %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Débit_horaire)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 6 / 10, size = 0.3, color = "blue") +
  geom_line(alpha = 4 / 10, size = 0.5, color = "blue") +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Débit Horaire (m3/s)") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(
      color = "grey",
      size = 0.25,
      linetype = 2
    ),
    legend.position = "none"
  ) +
  facet_zoom(
    xlim = as.POSIXct(c("2021-01-15 00:00:00", "2021-02-15 00:00:00")),
    y = TRUE, zoom.size = .5,
    split = FALSE, horizontal = TRUE
  ) +
  theme(zoom.y = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you once again! The code works properly, except for the `theme(zoom.y = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA))`. It says `Error:
! Theme element `zoom` is not defined in the element hierarchy.`. I have tried with simply `zoom =`instead of `zoom.y =, but still does not work. 
But except that all is good.

Comment: Hm. Could you check `packageVersion("ggforce")`. Mine is `0.4.1`. It should be available for versions >= 0.4.0ß

Comment: Yep, now it's good

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_zoom(y = Species == 'versicolor')
```

Like this? (Zooming in on the y-axis)